# Split a string up into rows by delimiter in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a very long string, with with data split up by a "|" as a delimiter. It looks something like this:

```
some data||some data||||
```

I want to split this line by line, to look like this:

```
some data|
|
some data|
|
|
|
```

But, by using replace | with |\r\n, I end up with something like this:

```
s
o
m
e

d
a
t
a
|
|
etc.
```

How do I split this the way I want to in NPP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the search string:

`\|`

With the replacement string:

`\|\r\n`

You are running the command in REGEX mode, and the `|` in the search string will be picked up as a REGEX operator, it simply needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 5):

Just use `Extended` `Search Mode` instead `Normal` or `Regular expression` ones.

[image: NPP extended search]

Comment: For those who are wondering(just like i was), `Search Mode` is found on the same pop-up screen where you do the `Replace`, at the bottom left of the window, at the time of this comment. 3 choices: Normal(default), Extended, and Regular Expression.

Comment: @jumping_monkey I hope that answer is informative enough now.

Comment: A picture tells a thousand words, well done. Although your find/replace should be the other way round to answer the OP's question, i can give you a +1 as it is informative enough to help others. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 1):

#### I want to replace `|` with `|<cr><lf>`

Note: `|` is a special character ([alternation operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)) in a regular expression, so it needs to be escaped using the escape character `\`.

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `\|`
- Set "Replace with" to `|\r\n`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

[image]

**Before**:

```
some data||some data||||
```

**After**:

```
some data|
|
some data|
|
|
|
```

---

#### Further reading

- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)